# Telerik Grid , Telerik Window and Confirm delete action

Tags: telerik-mvc

I have a Telerik Ajax bound grid containing a `Html.ActionLink` for deleting a record. On clicking this link, a Telerik Window opens which is contained within a `Html.BeginForm` tag.

In this form, there is a telerik Window having 2 buttons "Yes" and "No" for confirmation. This thing works pretty much fine but only problem is that when I delete a record, the entire page is refreshed which is not required.

I am thinking about converting Html.ActionLink to Ajax.ActionLink and Html.BeginForm to Ajax.BeginForm.

How can I Ajax-enable my Html.ActionLink and Html.BeginForm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the built in grid features. In the databinding section, declare your delete action

```
.DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
                                       .Select("_AjaxBinding","ControllerName")
                                       .Delete("_AjaxDelete", "ControllerName")
)
```

Then add a command button to the columns array

```
columns.Command( o => o.Delete().ButtonType( GridButtonType.Text ) );
```

and that's it. Your delete action will delete the record (takes an int id parameter) and then return `return _AjaxBinding();` at then end of the action.